# Finding matching files with Perl module File::Find::Rule

Tags: perl

I'n trying to use the `File::Find::Rule` module to find a specific file (`output.txt`) in a subdirectory, and if it is not there then search in the root directory to see if it exists.  The issue is that multiple output.txt files exist, so we should only be looking for others if the original is not found.

Basically the directory structure looks like this

```
top
    level-1-a
        level-2-a
            output.txt
        level-2-b
            output.txt
    level-1-b
        level-2-a
            output.txt
        level-2-b
            output.txt
```

Right now I have:

```
    @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name($output)->in($sub_dir);

    if ( ! @files ) {
        @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name($output)->in($root_dir);
    }
```

Where the behavior is, we look for output.txt in `\top\level-1-a` first, where it finds the matches in `level-2-a` and `level-2-b`.  If there are no matching files under `level-1-a`, we will then make the same call on `\top` to find the matches show up in the `level-1-b` directories.  Is there a cleaner way to check with that "if-else" idea?

Comment: It sounds like you want to get a list of all the matching files under some top-level directory, sort them, and then keep only the first element.

Comment: If $subdir is very large, you could avoid searching that part of the tree second time to speed things up. Otherwise, What you have looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the subdirectories one at a time. Here's an example. The `last` breaks out of the `for` loop as soon as soon as a subdirectory has been found that contains the required file

```
my @files;

for my $subdir ( 'level-1-a', 'level-1-b' ) {
    last if @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name($output)->in("/top/$subdir");
}
```